# Change color of area chart programmatically in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to change the color of the area chart after it is initially rendered.

In the JSFiddle demo after clicking the button you can see the color has changed when you either mouseover the data point or toggle the display by clicking on the legend to hide and then show again.

In both of these the main area color has not updated but the data points and legend has.

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/simonweston/tLwy5/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can change it dynamically but you need to manipulate the SVG DOM elements instead of the chart object:

```
$($('.highcharts-series').children()[0]).attr('fill','blue')
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark. I had thought of this but was hoping to do it via the highcharts API as IE8 is using VML and this will not work for VML.

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried changing it without luck, the only way is to re-create the chart as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/tLwy5/7/)

Comment: Thanks epoch. That is my current solution but it seems a little hacky. I need to render the chart to get some plotX and plotY values and then re-render the chart using these values to get accurate gradient stops. Not the prettiest solution but I guess it works.